# golangci-lint: exec: "git": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: go, golangci-lint

I'm trying to integrate `golangci-lint` on my project. I use `golangci-lint v1.49.0` that I install from `snap`. I've added ci config on my project but when I try to run it, it throws a very bizarre error.

```bash
$ golangci-lint run -v
INFO [config_reader] Used config file .golangci.yml 
INFO [lintersdb] Active 7 linters: [errcheck gosimple govet ineffassign staticcheck typecheck unused] 
INFO [loader] Go packages loading at mode 575 (files|name|types_sizes|deps|exports_file|compiled_files|imports) took 805.161254ms 
ERRO Running error: context loading failed: failed to load packages: failed to load with go/packages: err: exit status 1: stderr: go: github.com/user/repo@v1.3.4: git init --bare in /home/user/snap/golangci-lint/94/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/88980456e822acee6ee17242ca10c17af0281944db0d695e6f13a17951f304ee: exec: "git": executable file not found in $PATH
go: github.com/user/repo@v1.3.4: git init --bare in /home/user/snap/golangci-lint/94/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/88980456e822acee6ee17242ca10c17af0281944db0d695e6f13a17951f304ee: exec: "git": executable file not found in $PATH
INFO Memory: 10 samples, avg is 27.8MB, max is 27.8MB 
INFO Execution took 809.752753ms
```

`github.com/user/repo` isn't a real url, the one I use is private.

These are my config files

```yaml
# .gitlab-ci.yml

stages: 
  - test
  - build
  - sast
  - deploy
  - cleanup

golangci-lint:
  stage: test
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-build-images:golangci-lint-alpine
  script:
    - golangci-lint run -v
```

```yaml
# .golangci.yml

run:
  tests: false
  timeout: 10m
  skip-dirs:
    - "service/mocks"

output:
  format: colored-line-number
```

Why is it unable to read `git` in $PATH? I've been using git for years using this machine, this is my first time I got an error like this. I also just reinstalled using `sudo apt-get install git` just to make sure, but it still throws the same error. It looks like Git has already been installed, but it keeps throwing that error.

My OS is Ubuntu v20.04

I've also added the git path by running `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/git`, but it still keeps throwing the same error.

Comment: the thing is that you use this image `registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-build-images:golangci-lint-alpine`

what you could do is before executing the  `- golangci-lint run -v` is install git.